# difference using recursive functions python

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have lists which consist of random letters..

```
def similarity(out_list):

    i=0
    count=0
    while i<len(out_list):
        if out_list[i][-1]==out_list[i+1][-1]:
            count+=1

            return similarity(out_list[i][:-1]) + count
        elif out_list[i][-1]!=out_list[i+1][-1]:

            return similarity(out_list[i][:-1])
        i+=2

out_list=["ABABA","ACA","AGAGA","AAVA","XBX","ARAA","AADA","AAA","BABAB","ABA"]
similarity(out_list)
```

In my code I'm trying to find difference between list elements which are first and second, third and forth etc..

However since my function is recursive, the value of i is always 0 and I can't control other elements and I can't find the difference..

for ABABA and ACA the difference is 3 because first A and third A are the common in both words at same indexes.. so difference 5-2=3

what changes do my code require? Thank you.

Comment: What is your base case? I.E. you never return anything other than a recursive call

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing i as a parameter into your recursive function instead of setting it as 0 at the very start of the function. It's likely you would want to do something similar to count too.

Comment: Your code has multiple issues. For example, as a commenter above pointed out, there is no base case, as in nothing returns if it is passed an empty list and therefore your entire recursion fails. Secondly, if you want to keep track of variables, then pass them as updated parameters in the recursion instead of resetting them.